# PHP - PSR-4: Autoloader (composer) and multiple namespaces with the same root

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, psr-4

Currently all my classes are in one folder and are under one namespace:

```
"psr-4": {
   "RootNamespace\\": "lib/"
},
```

This is working well. As I'm adding more and more classes, I would like to put some logically related classes into deeper namespace level, but with the same root namespace. It should be something like this:

```
RootNamespace/Services (in 'lib/services' dir)
RootNamespace/Listeners (in 'lib/listeners' dir)
```

I suppose so that I don't need to change anything in my composer.json ps-4 autoload definition, but it's not working anymore.

How autoload definition should look like to achieve what I want to?

As I tested, solution below is not a good since, declarations seems to be overwritten

```
"psr-4": {
   "RootNamespace\\": "lib/",
   "RootNamespace\\Services\\": "lib/services/",
   "RootNamespace\\Listeners\\": "lib/listeners/"
},
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this, you just need to change the case on your folders (ie  `lib/services` -> `lib/Services` as your name space has an uppercase `S` and remove the extra stuff in `psr-4` just keep the main `"RootNamespace\\": "lib/",`

Comment: It's working when I run `composer dump-autoload`, but then vendor classes are not found. So I'm just a little stuck and have no idea what to do with it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PSR-4 Spec](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/):

> All class names MUST be referenced in a case-sensitive fashion.

Your configuration is accurate having different PSR-4 namespaces nested in the same directory. It should work, but may become confusing down the road.

```
"psr-4": {
    "RootNamespace\\": "lib/",
    "RootNamespace\\Services\\": "lib/services/",
    "RootNamespace\\Listeners\\": "lib/listeners/"
},
```

I recommend you either simply capitalize your directories to match the PSR spec, or move your `RootNamespace` out of the top level `lib/` directory.